# Tracing the surface of scour hole using image processing

Tags: image, matlab, octave

I have a soil scour hole that evolves with time i.e. scour depth is getting deeper with time. Scour hole seems to be parabolic in shape as shown here:

[image: ScourHole]

The requested surface is shown in blue line in Figure below:

[image: Requested Scour hole surface]

Since the scour hole is symmetric around the vertical axis, I cropped the image keeping the left half only. I have used the following code:

```
frm1 = imread('ScourHoleImage.jpg'); 
imshow(frm1); 
CrpWndo = zeros(1, 4); 
CrpWndo = [1017, 1127.6, 1606.2, 905.1]; 
frm1Crp = imcrop(frm1, CrpWndo); 
BW1 = im2bw(frm1Crp); 
boundaries = bwboundaries(BW1); 
boundaries = cell2mat(boundaries); 
imshow(BW1);
hold on
plot(boundaries(:,2), boundaries(:,1), '.g');
```

The above code gave me the following result:

[image: Obtained Results]

My questions are: How to remove the unwanted outlier marked pixels? And how to trace the soil surface only by a polyline curve?

Comment: One improvement could be to apply the same process to both halves of the scour hole, mirror one of the results, and merge them. This should reduce the noise.

Comment: If the *"experiment"* is under your control, maybe you could help yourself by improving the lighting. There is lots of extraneous light falling on the front of the tank, maybe you could poke the camera through a hole in some black velvet so less light hits the side of the tank - likewise the back wall behind the tank.

Comment: Hi Mark: Unfortunately, the experimental work is done and I have to use the results as is

Comment: Dear Cris, I will give your proposal a try and let you know.

Comment: If you have a time series of photos and the depth can only increase over time you have an additional info and a good starting point for an iterative approach. So you can suppress point which are bigger than some threshold from the previous detected curve. If you can upload a complete series I'm sure some of use would grab them and give it a try

Comment: Btw, you should also have a look at the different RGB channels. As I can see you have much more contrast on the blue channel

Comment: Dear Andy, both the scour depth and the scour diameter are increasing with time